# x = (int)(Math.random() * 1) what are the chances of 0 or 1?

Tags: java, math, random

that is the exact code then i have a switch for case 0: and case 1: it seems that the case 1: is coming out every time, i would like to have a 50/50 chance of 0 or 1 coming out is this the correct way or should i use 1.5 or how exactly does this work?

```
talka = (int)(Math.random() * 1);
        switch(talka)
        {

        case 0:
        {
            talk.setAnimationListener(this);
            talk.playtimes(1,24);
            startService(new Intent(this, love1.class));
            break;
        }
        case 1:
        {
            talk.setAnimationListener(this);
            talk.playtimes(1,12);
            startService(new Intent(this, love2.class));
            break;
        }
        }
```

Comment: Note that Math.random() returns double value between 0.0 and 1.0

Comment: half/half, since random() returns the uniformly distributed value.

Comment: He is casting the value to `int`

Comment: so if i use Math.round(Math.random() * 1) it would be more of a 50/50 chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has to do with the way the cast works.

In may test, Java was basically "trimming" the decimal result off and simply taking the "integer" component.  However, if I rounded the result, I got it flipping between 0 and 1.

Have a play

```
int ones = 0;
int zeros = 0;
for (int index = 0; index < 100; index++) {

    double rand = Math.random() * 1;
    if (Math.round(rand) == 1) {
        ones++;
    } else {
        zeros++;
    }
    System.out.println(rand + " - " + (int)Math.round(rand) + " - " + (int)Math.random() * 1);

}

System.out.println("Ones = " + ((float)ones / 100f));
System.out.println("Zeros = " + ((float)zeros / 100f));
```

It my simple test, I was getting around the 50/50 mark (+/-)

As pointed out by Hovercraft, better to use `java.util.Random` in this case.

Answer (score 8):

Just use a `java.util.Random` object and simply call `nextBoolean()` on it which will return true or false in a 50:50 distribution. Easy as `Math.PI`.

Answer (score 5):

This always rounds down.

```
talka = (int)(Math.random() * 1); // between 0 and 0
```

what you intended was perhaps

```
talka = (int)(Math.random() * 2); // between 0 and 1
```

However, using Math.random() get one bit is very inefficient.

If you use a Random with either

```
talka = random.nextInt(2);
```

or even better

```
talk.setAnimationListener(this);
if (random.nextBoolean()) {
        talk.playtimes(1,24);
        startService(new Intent(this, love1.class));
} else {
        talk.playtimes(1,12);
        startService(new Intent(this, love2.class));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The variable `talka` will always be zero; Math.random returns a value where 0 <= x < 1; since x must be less than 1 and the `(int)` cast truncates the decimal component, the integer result will always be 0.

From the Math.random documentation:

> Returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0.

Use `java.util.Random.nextBoolean()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

**-** It would be better and easier to go with `java.util.Random`.

**-** Use the `nextBoolean()` method of its.

**Eg:**

```
public class Rand {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Random r = new Random();

        System.out.println(r.nextBoolean());  // See there is a equal
                                                      // true-false division
    }

}
```